# No boot option after dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have been fighting with my pc to dual boot windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 for the past few days. I think I finally cracked it today and I'm fairly confident that everything is where it should be. However, I have one final hurdle to leap...

After finally installing Ubuntu in its own partition I couldn't log into it. There was no option to choose between the 2 OS and instead Windows just auto logged me in. So I ran Boot Repair from Live Ubuntu. Now, I have the exact opposite problem! I can see GRUB, it asks me to choose where to log in but the only option I have is Ubuntu.

If anyone has any ideas that would be great... Here is the link that Boot repair gave me, I think the answer is in [here in this Boot-Repair output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6803317/) but I don't understand it all.

Thanks in advance.

**Ps. I'm loving Ubuntu and I absolutely adore this forum!**

Comment: Boot into ubuntu and then run `sudo update-grub` command on terminal.

Comment: Well that was ridiculously easy! Thank you so much Avinash Raj! You're a beautiful person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the terminal, and type this in:

```
sudo update-grub
```

I had the exact same problem and it worked wonders for me.